# How many people use filters in the /review?

Tags: support, review-queues, statistics

I remember a graph that shows how many users give up /review when they are about the X review, some years back. One of the assumptions for those users dropping out the /review was that they are thrown a bunch of posts that reads Klingon to them. Is there stats about how many users use filtering by queue? By amount of reviews under their belt?

Comment: Fortunately, this information is stored in a clean, indexed table, so I can pull this information in about 5 minutes flag. Ha-ha, no, of course it's all in a big character-separated property bag so figuring it out will take hours plus blood sacrifice. Probably not gonna get to it today.

Comment: @Shog9 have you heard of this site called "sarcasmoverflow"? I'm sure they will like users like you :P.

Comment: I almost always filter by tags

Comment: For me, it depends on the review queue.  I filter close votes always.  I rarely filter suggested edits, electing to skip often because that queue is not nearly as full.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Also, edit suggestions don't need filters as much. If someone is abusing boldface and quote markdown to turn a post into a pinball machine, you don't need to know the subject to reject it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth that's true.  Every now and then, there is a minor code fix on an answer in a language I don't know.  Since I can't verify the edit comment "fixed syntax" I have to skip.

Comment: If I think about it, I use one of the "link" filters, but I only discovered filters by topic a couple of days ago. Imagine: When I was new to the privilege I just did *not* see the relatively small "filter" link next to `Review|Close Votes`. It doesn't really get one's attention, once you're immersed "in" the page, with all the newness, the information, the big blue buttons...

Comment: I didn't know there was a filter. Maybe I'll give it another try.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are [some stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360722/51) as of February 2021 (before the UX refresh for Review Queues):

| Queue | % Overall | % Filtered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **First Post** | 25.70% | 0.93% |
| **Suggested Edit** | 22.52% | 0.57% |
| **Triage** | 16.94% | N/A |
| **Close Vote** | 10.45% | 11.63% |
| **Low Quality** | 8.86% | 0.26% |
| **Late Answer** | 8.75% | 0.02% |
| **Reopen Votes** | 6.63% | 0.53% |
| **Helper** | 0.15% | N/A |

Answer (score 19):

Ok, here's some rough data:

| Name | Reviews | Users | ReviewsByUsersFiltering | UsersFiltering |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Suggested Edit | 1790421 | 130330 | 17898 (1.00%) | 524 (0.40%) |
| Triage | 1986159 | 21462 | 0 (0.00%) | 0 (0.00%) |
| First Post | 814768 | 15368 | 9126 (1.12%) | 244 (1.59%) |
| Late Answer | 303824 | 9295 | 377 (0.12%) | 42 (0.45%) |
| Low Quality Posts | 662708 | 5903 | 35496 (5.36%) | 212 (3.59%) |
| Close Votes | 544876 | 5519 | 259162 (47.56%) | 1317 (23.86%) |
| Reopen Vote | 192571 | 2751 | 15269 (7.93%) | 161 (5.85%) |
| Helper | 47328 | 1758 | 278 (0.59%) | 54 (3.07%) |

This covers reviews in the past 365 days, and users who *currently* have a filter active in the respective queue. Critically, it miscategorizes reviews when someone has changed their filter preferences during the past 365 days by assuming those preferences are static. So... Take this with a big grain of salt.

Comment: I presume that the users using filtering are also the ones with more reviews under their belt? Median reviews in timeframe for users using filtering?

Comment: I'm definitely one of the users skewing this data as you describe; I use filters a lot but always reset back to all the possible "close reasons" (in the CVQ, for example) when I am finished. I'm guessing real-time data collection would be, erm, costly, for this?

Comment: Yeah; I could give you stats for a few days, but it'd take a good long while to gather and probably be just as skewed.

Comment: Maybe include a post parameter in the POST /add request with the filter options? For logging purposes?

Comment: Triage doesn't allow its participants to filter posts by things. I don't think there's a point in including it in this "how many people use filters" chart.

Comment: Excluding it would've been more work, @doru - plus, this way if anyone needs a handy table of how many people use review (as I did just the other day), it's here.