# Should I vote on mediocre posts?

Tags: discussion, voting

When I'm looking at questions and answers about topics I am familiar with, I think I use my up and down votes appropriately when I do use them. (I certainly try to, anyway, and I hope I'm successful.) But there are a lot of times when a post does not seem to be good enough for an upvote or bad enough for a downvote. I've been wondering if I should try to make more of an effort to make the distinction and use more of my votes, rather than only voting for things I think are especially good or bad.

What I'm thinking is: if I see a post that I think is useful, I give it an upvote. If I think it is not useful, I give it a downvote. But doesn't everything have to be one or the other? If it isn't useful, it must be not useful, right? Or is that a harmful oversimplification? I want to try to be a good citizen, but I'm having a hard time deciding whether voting on mediocre posts will add value or just create noise.

I'm aware that I have a limited number of votes available daily, and there could be some value in conserving them for cases that are especially good or bad, but at this point I don't think I ever get close enough to the limit to need to worry about that too much.

Comment: The common advice given for folks in review queues is "There's no shame in using Skip" and that probably applies here too. If you don't feel you know enough about a topic to tell whether the question is useful, skip voting it.

Comment: It's really your decision.

Comment: I agree, and I typically don't vote at all on topics I'm not familiar with, unless I come across something just egregious. I'm just trying to decide whether or not it would be useful for me to be more opinionated in topics I _am_ familiar with.

Comment: [Using filters may make you less likely to feel like that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322016/792066)

Comment: I upvoted your mediocre post. I also favorited it. I'm eager to learn what comes out of this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I was careful not to make the question too good, in order to allow for that sort of meta irony.

Comment: In terms of voting, quality is more important than quantity, right?

Comment: You could also add a comment. "This answer could be improved if ....".

Comment: I always upvote, both answer and solution, in case it personally helps me out. Otherwise, I just don't vote.

Comment: Maybe substituting "_sufficiently good_" for "_mediocre_" will allow you to not vote more easily?  I'll up-vote personally helpful answers/questions (of (almost) any quality) and "outstanding" answers (well researched, well presented etc.) if I spot them in passing, but the majority of answers that "do the job" but don't directly affect me I'll just leave.  IMHO, many answers are neither "brilliant" nor "dreadful".

Comment: "Doesn't everything have to be one or the other?" No, you're falling prey to the [false dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma). Voting to close as POB; whether you vote on a question is really up to you and no one else.

Comment: 0 is a real fair score for mediocre posts, isn't it? Do the math.

Comment: @TylerH I thought it was ok for "discussion" questions to be subjective.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Some subjectivity is fine but this question is just asking whether or not you should vote on questions... that's really just a matter of opinion, e.g. how are you feeling in that moment.

Comment: This happens to me when I am faced with—what I consider—a really stupid question. It's on topic but just stupid and you can't just downvote on that ground. I often feel perplexed and wish I had a way to deal with these.

Comment: what does an opinion-based hold in meta mean?  'cause most questions in meta I see have opinion-based answers (not all, but most).  (or .. .given the question itself ... maybe I missed a joke here ...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I normally do not vote on mediocre (neither useful nor unuseful) posts. This also includes posts which I cannot decide its usefulness in the given time (as I read it).

To do otherwise may give wrong signals to the other readers:

1. To vote it up may hint some people (including the OP) that the answer somehow helpful (although, according to our understanding, it is actually not)
2. On the other hand, to vote it down falsely hints the opposite. This may, occasionally, attract more downvotes while the posts actually don't deserve that.

So if you cannot make up your mind, it is OK not to vote. Just leave the posts alone.

*(After all, we are one big community with various skills and talents here. What we cannot judge by ourselves, other members of the community might be capable of. As we cannot possibly be involved in all posts, trust other community members to vote up/down the posts we cannot decide.)*

Comment: I do agree Ian, but I wonder if there is the possibility that not voting on posts you can't decide the overall usefulness or lack of use would lead to the next Linus Torvalds, Tim Berners-Lee or that guy what worked with Steve Jobs and stuff, without recognition for their labors and buried at the bottom of the pile. Hence I wonder if it's a good idea to upvote posts where the bits you can work out are good, overall.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter ah yes. Sadly, there *is* such possibility... :( but the point here is if we do *not* understand/cannot make up our mind, it is then not in our capacity to be in position of upvoting/downvoting because of the ambivalent responses we have. If we try to up/down vote, there must be at least one side of the decision which we judge worth doing. And if that is the case, we should follow our judgement. Therefore, what I am saying here is that if we cannot make up our mind, we *shouldn't* vote because we *couldn't* value the posts rightly.

Answer (score 33):

I agree that the things are not black and white and that, in fact, there's a huge gray area. Generally, with mediocre posts, you have two options:

- If it leans towards the black area (downvote), write a better answer (since you say you're familiar with the topic) and optionally downvote the original one if you feel it still deserves it
- If it leans towards the white area (upvote), suggest improvements using the comments section, and if the OP agrees with you and improved the answer, I think they deserve that upvote

And of course, the third (yup, I said two) option:

- If you really can't make where it leans, just leave it in the grey area, don't vote.

---

Don't forget that voting is personal and there are no super-strict rules about it and no answer here should change that.

Comment: What I'm wondering (and maybe didn't express very well in the question) is whether or not there really _is_ a gray area, or if in cases where I _think_ there is, I just haven't looked at it hard enough. Basically, does every question and answer deserve a vote one way or the other?

Comment: I think it's "primarily opinion-based". :)  In my opinion, the gray area does exist, and I pretty much use what I wrote you as a guideline.

Comment: @Don'tPanic When in Doubt, Leave it Out. For me the area is maybe 80% gray. I downvote only if it's both wrong and useless (I've seen tons of wrong but useful answers and vice versa) and upvote only if it's really good. I don't feel the need for voting when the community is big enough.

Comment: @maaartinus I'm curious what you mean by "wrong but useful answers".

Comment: @Don'tPanic A part of it, or even the conclusion may be wrong, but there's a part from which I learn something new. No, no example at hand.

Answer (score 4):

Preface: This is just outlook, users are allowed to vote as they see fit.
<sup>(*with exception of abuse of course*)</sup>

In my opinion the voting outlook for questions and answers is different, perhaps not extremely different, but different nonetheless. I feel this is obvious, and offer a simple example supporting the notion in that it requires reputation to downvote an answer.

As such, and since "posts" tend to refer to both questions and answers, the answer here is going to be broken down a bit.

**Posts**

The overall outlook for all posts is to vote based on content. Some of the reasoning behind this is that voting based on content are votes that are

- giving signal to other users
- allowing good content to bubble to the top
- not "punishing" users with downvotes
- not "rewarding" users with upvotes (to counter punitive downvotes)
- not targeted towards a certain user (i.e. serial voting)
- common sense

**Questions**

Voting specifically on questions is a little different, as evidenced by not only the lack of reputation penalty for downvoting, but also by the difference in tooltip (title attribute)

> ▲ This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear
>   ▼ This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

From my perspective, any time I come across a question I would have asked when trying to solve a problem, I upvote it because it saved me time, even if the post was not perfectly written. There is a famous saying,

> Don't let perfection be the enemy of progress

and I think that applies here to questions in general. Just because a question has some imperfection does not mean the time spent generating it should be overlooked if it saved you time.

Of course, there is the flip side of these where the question is not useful or well researched, but I think we can all identify those fairly easily. You know what to do.

The topic here was not for "best" versus "worst", it was for middle; and in the middle ground, if it was answerable, unique-ish, and stood the test of time I don't see why you wouldn't want to upvote it.

**Answers**

This was broken apart for the reason that each aspect was different, and so are answers. The tooltip is much simpler for answers,

> ▲ This answer is useful
>   ▼ This answer is not useful

and I think it is simpler with good reason. Answers are more context based. A mediocre answer where there is no other answer may deserve an upvote because at its core it was useful in deriving some information from. However, a mediocre answer where there is another good answer doesn't necessarily need an upvote in my opinion - otherwise there is sort of a mixed signal being sent. Clearly if both answers are good that is a different story, but again the topic here is the mediocre answer, and in that case when a better one is present, I see no need to upvote the mediocre one.

Answer (score -3):

I usually decide how much the answer is worth for me, and vote depending on if that answer already arrived at that vote.

So let's say, an answer is worth a score of 5 to me. Is it lower than that value, then I upvote. If it is higher than that value, I don't do anything (downvoting an otherwise ok answer seems impolite to me).

Otherwise, if people only vote without having a look at the other people's votes, you get (happens quite often) a mediocre early answer with hundreds of upvotes, while much better late answers receive a lot less attention and thus never get the visibility that mediocre early post got.

Comment: It's people like you that are the reason that the Meta Effect exists!!!! ;-)

Comment: From what I understand, my post doesn't have anything to do with the Meta Effect. Can you please expound?

Comment: Do not vote based on existing votes.  Pretend the votes are not there and it is at zero.  Would you vote up or down?  That is how you should vote.  You should not let previous votes dictate how you vote.  Voting the way everyone else does because that is how they are voting can be considered the "meta-effect"

Comment: But I am saying the exact opposite. From what you say, you would vote up if it already has a lot of votes and not vote, if it does not have any votes.
What I mean is rather upvote a mediocre answer that hasn't received any attention while not upvoting a mediocre answer that has a lot of upvotes already.

Comment: I understand that you aren't saying that you would vote like everyone else had, but I still don't prefer this approach for myself. I would rather vote based on my own perception of the value of the post without considering other votes or lack thereof.

Comment: I see what you mean. What I mean is that I vote, based on if that post already arrived at the value that it has for me. If I think this post is worth 5 upvotes and it is there already, then I won't upvote. Otherwise you get (happens a lot) a mediocre early post with hundreds of upvotes and much better late posts that receive a lot less and are thus less visible than the one early post.

Comment: @Dakkaron I agree. Upvoted. It is a lot harder to pull a great answer out from the bunch of mediocre or not-very-good-answer-but-nevertheless-having-plenty-upvotes answers once such answers have received too many upvotes. I think you should add your last comment into your post, pal. Otherwise you will get more downvotes before you know it... See my answer: downvotes invite downvotes.

Comment: @Ian: thanks for that comment, I added my last comment into the post.

Comment: @Dakkaron maybe make your last paragraph the first one. Changed my down vote to an up vote after reading it all the way (shouldn't knee-jerk vote, but that happens sometimes, too).

Comment: +1'd your answer because it was in the negative. If it was 0 I would have left it alone, since the answer I prefer is already at the top, and your answer is not in anyway bad or off topic or in need of editing.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum: You are right, I'll edit that.

Comment: @user6170930: Totally my point ;)