# If the question is ok, should it be upvoted?

Tags: discussion, questions, triage

In the triage queue stack encourages to upvote questions which show research and a sincere effort. I see consensus on many many questions, but never any upvotes on either of them. What is the correct action to take?

Comment: Upvote good, downvote bad, don't vote ok.

Comment: Relevant: [Should I vote on mediocre posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322263/should-i-vote-on-mediocre-posts)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Questions which enter the triage queue are not up to snuff. The intent is to allow others to help get them up to snuff.

As a general principle, 0-scored posts are precisely those meet the minimum standards of the site but really have nothing else to recommend them (not interesting, novel, etc).

So if a post went through triage, and was made adequate for the site, not below our standards, but still fundamentally no different or better than the other 10,000 we get every day, 0 is an appropriate, even correct, score.

Another way of putting it is: an upvote means “this is the kind of content I want to see more of on this site”, a downvote means the opposite, and no vote is “meh; there’s nothing wrong with this, but nothing special about it either. It won’t hurt us to have more like this, but I’m not going to encourage/reward it either”.

Or, to really boil it down to its essentials, I’ll echo <s>the Incredible Hulk’s</s> [@MisterMiyagi’s précis in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406133/if-the-question-is-ok-should-it-be-upvoted/406134#comment832370_406133):

> **Upvote good, downvote bad, don't vote ok.**

Comment: Vote on, vote off.